# How to reference data files, APA-style?

Tags: style, citations

I'm preparing an assignment which requires two MS Project files to be submitted, containing WBS/GANTT charts for a fictional project, and a textual explanation of what I did and why, which.

(All the files will be submitted electronically, zipped.)

For the assignment, I'm required to include referencing, "APA style".

So I figure I need to reference the attached MS Project files from within my explanation document.

Is there a proper way to reference data files using APA style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following web site for examples on how to reference *other media* in APA format.

[APA Referencing Guide](http://www.usq.edu.au/library/help/referencing/apa)

In particular, look at the links, [Other electronic media](http://www.usq.edu.au/library/help/referencing/apa#electronic) and [Audiovisual and other media](http://www.usq.edu.au/library/help/referencing/apa#av).

Alternatively, have a look at the following word document for examples on how to cite data using the APA reference style.

[Citing online Census and statistical data in APA format](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.alfredstate.edu%2Flibrary%2FAPA%2520format-%2520Census%2520and%2520statistical%2520sources%2520Portrait.doc&ei=EgaQTrrAJMKViQfynbCeDg&usg=AFQjCNEhAqzL8KLo1HvzSnuQUjvALw5fng)

Hope this helps.